# Generate a bifurcation diagram using the provided Matlab code

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, numerical-methods, ode, diagram

Dear Experts and Senior Colleagues,
I would like to create the following figure using the provided code. However, it seems to be taking an extended amount of time with no visible results.
[image]

Here is my Matlab code, which is not providing any results.

```
clc;close all;clear;
results = [];

tmax = 300;

r1 = 0.36; a = 0.1; k1 = 0.36; k2 = 0.48; r2 = 1; deltav = 0.2; deltaz = 0.036;

x0 = 0.5; y0 = 0; v0 = 0.3; z0 = 0.1; 

for b = 0:0.1:30
    ode_system = @(t, y) [
        r1 * y(1) * (1 - y(1)) - a * y(1) * y(3) - k1 * y(1) * y(4);
        a * y(1) * y(3) - k2 * y(2) * y(4) - y(2);
        b * y(2) - a * y(1) * y(3) - deltav * y(3);
        r2 * y(2) * y(4) - deltaz * y(4)
    ];

    [t, sol] = ode45(ode_system, [0, tmax], [x0, y0, v0, z0]);

    results = [results; b * ones(length(t), 1), sol(:, 1)];

    x0 = sol(end, 1);
    y0 = sol(end, 2);
    v0 = sol(end, 3);
    z0 = sol(end, 4);
end

figure;
plot(results(:, 1), results(:, 2), '.');
xlabel('b');
ylabel('x');
title('Bifurcation Diagram');
grid on;
```

Comment: Such systems usually either explode or converge to an equilibrium point. In the latter case, the solution is an almost straight line, but the eigenvalues of the Jacobian limit the step size for explicit methods. Change `ode45` for an implicit method to get much larger step sizes. // Please describe the intended plot more exactly, it seems you use (and store) too much data. // The default tolerances are selected to produce usable plots of the solution function, they are accurate enough for the pixel display but not much more. // You might want to switch off the "Refine" computations.

Comment: Try out for  speed-up: Set `tmax = 3`, only store the pair `b, sol(end,1)`. To find out what happens, print a message directly after the computation has concluded, it might take so long to plot due to the ten thousands of graphics objects.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My code works for tmax=32 but does not for tmax>32.

Comment: You should explore what you actually get as data. As you give a time span, the output consists of all internal steps and 3 additional points per internal segment. With an explicit method the step size is restricted to some small value due to the stiffness of the ODE, so that you get many many points in the output of each integration. And you plot them all. The figure object expects to plot up to a few ten thousand points, it is not optimized to hold more, as usually more points do not make a perceptible difference. So prune your data, replace the time span with a list of sampling times,...

Answer (score 0):

You get two types of behavior, convergence towards an equilibrium (having `y(1)=1`) and oscillations, probably limit cycles, but strange attractors are not excluded. Perhaps there are even different modes of oscillations for different segments of the parameter `b`. In the second case you want the span of the oscillation in the plot, that is, plot the extrema in `y(1)`. These extrema are located where the derivative of `y(1)` is zero.

The Matlab ODE solvers have a nice mechanism to locate and register zeros of functions on the solution called "events". So build an event function following specifications

```
    function [val, term, dir] = equi1(t,y)
      val = r1*(1-y(1))-a*y(3)-k1*y(4);
      term = false;
      dir = 0;
    end
```

Insert it into the parameter list

```
    opts = odeset('RelTol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-8);
    opts = odeset(opts, 'Events', @(t,y) equi1(t,y));
```

and call the solver with the parameter list

```
    [t, sol, t_e, sol_e, ind_e] = ode45(ode_system, [0:0.1:tmax], [x0, y0, v0, z0], opts);
    if length(t_e)==0 % no oscillation, monotonic to the equilibrium
      results = [results; b * ones(4, 1), sol(end-3:end, 1)];
    else % there were maxima and minima
      results = [results; b * ones(length(t_e), 1), sol_e(:, 1)];
    end%if
```

This then gives a plot like

[image: bifurcation plot]

I did this in octave, there `ode23s` produced a less wiggly diagram, `ode15s` had problems with the step size along the way.